# Temporarily disable write (INSERT, UPDATE, etc.) of MySQL connection session with PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Is there any way for an ordinary MySQL user (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE) to connect to the server with temporarily less privileges (only SELECT) for that particular **connection session**?

I'm asking this is because we have a lot of MySQL users on our servers managing thousands of databases. Each of the users would be responsible for e.g. 50 databases. Now that they need to create APIs and release public access to the databases, it's best to use MySQL users with only SELECT privilege to access the databases. We can create a global user for this purpose but then it would have the privilege to access ALL of the databases.

So it's best to restrict access to certain databases with only the SELECT privilege.

Is there any way to use existing MySQL users and then only modify its privileges (revoking INSERT, UPDATE) on a **connection basis**?

## UPDATE

I know how to revoke privileges for MySQL users in general but what I need is to only revoke privileges in a particular connection session so the revoke won't affect other MySQL connections by the same user.

Any idea? Or is it simply impossible?

Comment: Might [this](https://serverfault.com/a/115954) help?

Comment: @Geshode That would also affect other sessions of the same user that needs the write privileges?

Comment: It seems to be permanent, but I guess, if you can't find another solution, then you can use it to write a program to change it for each session. But I agree, that an easier solution, would be nicer.

Comment: Have you tried it with [revoke](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html)?

Comment: @Geshode, I know how to grant and revoke privileges in general but I need to only grant / revoke them temporarily per connection.

Comment: I thought, you wanted to revoke the rights for a specific user for a specific table. Sorry for my misunderstanding. So, you want to revoke the rights for a specific user to a specific table in a session, but in a different session the user should have no revoked rights for that specific table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-changes.html says:

> A grant table reload affects privileges for each existing client
>   connection as follows:
>
> - Table and column privilege changes take effect with the client's next    request.
> - Database privilege changes take effect the next time the client    executes a USE db_name statement.
> - Global privileges and passwords are unaffected for a connected    client. These changes take effect only for subsequent connections.

In other words, privileges are checked on every request — i.e., before every query. There's only one copy of privileges in memory per server, and all sessions check the same set of loaded privileges. There's no way for different sessions for that user to enforce different privileges.

In an application I worked on previously, we solved a similar problem to the one you describe. We created two MySQL users for each application: one with full privileges on one database, and one with read-only privileges on that one database.

The app would log in using either one set of credentials or the other, and that choice would determine what privileges it had.

Answer (score -1):

REVOKE all the privileges first,then GRANT the privileges which you want

Answer (score -2):

You should use grant privilege for this type of problem.

```
GRANT privilege,[privilege],.. ON privilege_level 
TO user [IDENTIFIED BY password]
[REQUIRE tsl_option]`enter code here`
[WITH [GRANT_OPTION | resource_option]];
```

You can grant multiple privileges in a single **GRANT** statement.